# Option.map (null) returns Some (null)

Tags: scala, null

I want to this code snippet return me `None`  instead of `Some(null)`:

```
Option(x).map(x.getNullValue) // returns Some(null)
```

I heard `Scalaz` library has features to handle such case. So how I can achieve my goal using both: `scalaz` and standard Scala library?

Comment: What's wrong with `Option(x.getNullValue)`?

Comment: @ipoteka `x` can be also null, so I'm wrapping it as `Option` too

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could use `flatMap` together with the `Option.apply` method here instead of pulling in `scalaz`:

```
Option(initialValue).flatMap(x => Option(x.getNullValue))
```

This works since the `Option.apply` method treads `null` intelligently:

```
val x: String = null
Option(x) //None
Option("foo") //Some("foo")
```

So if you know the value outright, you can simply do:

```
Option(x.getNullValue)
```

You can also use other methods on `Option` like `filter`, `orElse`, or `getOrElse`, depending on the situation:

```
Option(initialValue).map(_.getNullValue).filter(_ != null)
Option(initialValue).orElse(Option(x.getNullValue))
Option(x.getNullValue).getOrElse(defaultValue)
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about scalaz, but in the standard library your only choice really is to filter out the `null` value. `map` simply maps `A => B` and expects that `B` will not be `null`.

Example:

```
object HasNull {
    def getNull: Any = null
}

scala> Option(HasNull).map(_.getNull).filter(_ != null)
res24: Option[Any] = None
```

Or

```
scala> Option(HasNull).flatMap(a => Option(a.getNull))
res25: Option[Any] = None
```

Alternatively, you can use a little implicit magic to avoid the `Option` boilerplate:

```
implicit def toOpt[A](a: A): Option[A] = Option(a)

scala> Option(HasNull).flatMap(_.getNull)
res3: Option[Any] = None
```

Using `flatMap` still is the key, because it expects an `Option[B]`. But `getNull` is of type `B`, so the implicit conversion will be used, which will wrap the nullable in `Option.apply` again.

Answer (score 1):

As others already wrote, you can do it using flatMap. And a very similar approach is:

```
case class User(name: String)
val users = List(null, User("John"), User(null))
for{
  userDb <- users
  user <- Option(userDb)
  name <- Option(user.name)
} yield name
```

The problem with `None` is that you do not know which `None` you get: user doesn't exist or name? In this case scalaz can help you:

```
for{
  userDb <- users
  user <- Option(userDb) \/> "No user found."
  name <- Option(user.name) \/> "No name provided."
} yield name
```

But this is another story. You can find awesome explanation about this use case [here](https://speakerdeck.com/bwmcadams/scala-exchange-2014-a-skeptics-look-at-scalaz-gateway-drugs-a-practical-exploration) ([video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GGPE-Hh0L1I)).